# Possible to configure models in Rails to pull data from different data sources?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, model

Our app requires pulling data from different data sources: one a MySQL database and another a Mongo database.

Is it possible to config models to pull data from different data sources and leverage Rails.cache to make queries fast? Right now, the config files in Rails only seem to support a single data source.

We're on Rails 3.0.6.

Comment: You might want to upgrade your app to 3.0.19 for security reasons: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/1/8/Rails-3-2-11-3-1-10-3-0-19-and-2-3-15-have-been-released/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails provided convention to use multiple database.Let me show you how to use Mango and Mysql.

Consider mysql as primary database. So a configuration for mysql goes inside config/database.yml

```
config/database.yml
  development:
    #dev config goes here
  test:
    #test config goes here
  production:
    #production config goes here
```

And consider Mongo now. Place another configuration for Mongo in config/mongo_database.yml

```
 config/mongo_database.yml
    development:
      #dev config goes here
    test:
      #test config goes here
    production:
      #production config goes here
```

Now we connect User model to mysql:

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     #Active record by default connects with the primary database configuration
   end
```

Now we connect Product model to Mongo:

```
   class Product
     include MongoMapper::Document
   end
```

Also you need to intialize mongo setttings in config/intializers/mongo.rb

```
config/intializers/mongo.rb 
Mongoid.configure do |config|
  config = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config", "mongo_database.yml"))[Rails.env]
  host = config["host"]
  config.master = Mongo::Connection.new.db(config["database"])
end
```

Comment: what if we use mongomapper?

Comment: @Crashalot You should go through the documentation for mongomapper.

Answer (score 0):

**YES.**

For MySQL:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

For Mongo:

```
class ExampleTwo
  include MongoMapper::Document
  ...
end
```

Comment: then in database.yml, we just set up adapters for different data sources? or what else do we need to do? thanks!

Comment: Install and configure active_record and mongomapper (if needed) and follow their setup instructions. I believe databases.yml is only for active_record and that mongo has it's own file, but I would have to check the docs to know.